# Decode binary response from serial

Tags: python, decode, pyserial

I switch scales UART to Raspbery via USB-TTL.
Scales send data in ASCII in 8 bit chanks

[image]

```
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', 9600, timeout=0.5)
>>> ser.isOpen()
True
>>> ser.inWaiting()
4095
>>> ser.read()
b'\xfb'
>>> ser.read(200)
b'\xfb\x9b\xa3\x8d\x9b\xbf1\xbf\xe5\xac\x00V\xd5Ze\xfd\xbf\xbf\xbfL\xa3\x8d\x9b\xbf1\xbf\xe5\xeb\x00V\xd5Ze\xfd\xbf\xbf\xbf\x93\xa3\x8d\x9b\xfc1\xbf\xe5\xeb\x00V\xd5Ze\xfd\xbf\xbf\xbf\x93\xa3\x8d\x9b\xbf1\xfc\xe5\xeb\x00V\x15Ze\xfd\xbf\xbf\xbf\x93\xa3\x8d\x9b\xbf\xc4\xbf\xe5\xeb\x00V\xd5Ze\xfd\xbf\xbf\xbf\x93\x8c\x8d\x9b\xbf1\xbf\xe5\xeb\x00V\xd5Ze\xfd\xbf\xbf\xbf\x93\xa3\x8d\x9b\xbf\xc4\xbf\xe5\xeb\x00V\xd5Ze\xfd\xfc\xbf\xbf\x93\xa3\x8d\x9b\xbf1\xbf\xe5\xeb\x00V\xd5\x1a\\V\xfb\xfb\xfb\x9b\xa3\x8d\x9b\xbf1\xfc\xe5\xeb\x00V\xd5Ze\xfd\xbf\xfc\xbf\x93\xa3\x8d\x9b\xbf1\xbf\xe5\xeb\x00V\xd5Z\xc9\xfd\xbf\xbf\xbf\x93\xa3\x8d\x9b\xbf1\xbf\x94\xeb\x00V\x15Ze\xfd\xbf\xbf\xbf\x93'
>>> ser.read(200).decode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

So I got some hex codes, but expect to get something like this: 'ST, GS 0.0 g '
I can't read line here, it just never ends. Earlier I used USR-TCP232-T2 converter and the result I recieved was like 'S 0.0 g
ST, GS 0.0 g
ST, GS 0.0 g
ST, G'

I tried `binascii.hexlify(bytearray(b'\xfb\xfb\xfb\x9b\xa3\x8d\x9b\xbf1\xfc\xe5\xeb\x00'))`
and then decoded it to ascii but the result was like ûûû£¿1üåë - far from what I expected.

Could you please help me to understand how to convert that hex mess into a meaningful string?

Comment: Are you sure that 9600 is the correct baud rate for the scale?  That looks like the kind of garbage you get with an incorrect baud rate.  In any case, there's no way to "convert" this to anything useful, you need to fix the underlying problem with the connection or settings.

Comment: Seems that it is the case, thank you so much. Change baud rate - the result also changes.  Seems that it worth to keep converter as it was.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII goes only to `127`. What you want is extended ASCII, because you have a character `163` (£).

Use encoding `latin-1`.

Comment: '¿1üåë\x00VÕZeý¿ü¿\x93£\x8d\x9d¿1¿åë\x00VÕZÉý¿¿¿\x93£\x8d\x9d¿1¿\x94ë\x00V\x95Zeý¿¿¿\x93£\x8d\x9d¿Ä¿åë\x00VÕZeýü¿¿\x93£\x8d\x9d¿1¿åë\x00VÕZeý¿¿¿L£\x8d\x9d¿1¿åë\x00VÕZeý¿¿¿\x93£\x8d\x9dü1¿åë\x00VÕZeý¿¿¿\x93£\x8d\x9d¿1üåë\x00VÕZeý¿¿¿\x93£\x8d\x9d¿Ä¿åë\x00VÕZeý¿¿¿\x93£\x1a\x9d¿1¿åë\x00VÕZ\x91õûûû\x9b£\x8d\x9d¿1¿\x94ë\x00VÕZeý¿¿¿\x93£\x8d\x9dü1¿åë\x00VÕZeñûûû\x9b£\x8d\x9d¿1¿å¬\x00VÕZeý¿¿¿L£\x8d\x9d¿1¿åë\x00VÕZeý¿¿¿\x93£\x8d\x9dü1¿åë\x00VÕZeý¿¿¿\'
- this is what I get with latin-1 if decoding. I can not do anything with encoding as scales have factory SW.

Comment: Well, you either receive wrong data, or you are missing some important detail about its format.